# What does this do in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to figure out some code in Laravel by reading the docs and stuff. I came across a piece of code that I cant quit figure out what it is doing. Could someone explain this? Here is the piece of code in the project I am working on:

```
//  Create placeholders for the mobile app's video settings
$publicVideosEnabled  = ( $settings['publicVideosEnabled'] == 1 );
```

I am specifically asking about `$settings['publicVideosEnabled'] == 1` section.

Thanks everyone!

EDIT: For more information, here is where some of the variables are coming from:

```
$location = Location::find($location_id);
$settings = $this->apiHelper->getFormattedLocationSettings($location);
$publicVideosEnabled  = ( $settings['publicVideosEnabled'] == 1 );
```

I am trying to add this line of code:

```
$notificationsEnabled = ( $settings['notificationsEnabled'] == 1);
```

But I am getting this error:

> Undefined index: notificationsEnabled at `$notificationsEnabled = ( $settings['notificationsEnabled'] == 1);`

Comment: Well it checks if the setting 'publicVideosEnabled' is equal to 1.

Comment: Where would ['publicVideosEnabled'] be coming from?

Comment: You have some custom code handling reading the settings, `$this->apiHelper->getFormattedLocationSettings($location)`.  Why not grep your code for "publicVideosEnabled" and see if you can figure out where the setting is being read from (it might also be in a database I guess).

Comment: Yeah, I've searched every file and it is only on that one line.

Comment: Maybe a database table called settings or similar, just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$settings['publicVideosEnabled']` equals `1` then `$publicVideosEnabled` is **true**, otherwise it is **false**.

Comment: Where is ['publicVideosEnabled'] coming from?

Comment: It's a key in a `$settings` array. I don't know where it is coming from. Maybe it is evaluated somewhere earlier. Showing one line of code is like telling the doctor `I feel bad`.

Comment: I understand. I didn't mean to get exact answers of "oh this line calls this line which does this", just mainly syntactically. Thank you for your help

Comment: I added some more information to maybe help out what i am going through.

Comment: And what is the problem now?